# Printing to console in Pycharm Django views.py

Tags: python, django, debugging, console, pycharm

I am new to Pycharm (v2019.2) and Django (2.2.4). I am trying to understand pieces of code in various files and am trying to print data to the windows at the bottom of Pycharm, i.e. Run, manage.py, Terminal, Python Console.

I've tried various solutions. I've added LOGGING to `settings.py` file according to the Django tutorial and importing `logging`. Nothing came out. I've also tried editing Run > Configurations in Pycharm but to no avail.

```py
#views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Customer

def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        groups = Customer.objections.select_related('group').values('name', 'address', 'group__name', 'group__limit')
        print(groups)
        for item in groups:
            print(item)
        context = {'group_list': {'data': list(groups)}}
        return render(request, 'index.html', context, request.user)
    else:
        return redirect('/accounts/login')
```

My page loads fine but I just don't see any output to my consoles.

Comment: How are you running your django server? The pycharm "Run" console should print everything you `print`, if you're running via a run configuration. You should see it below the **runserver** startup log ("System check identified 0 issues ... Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:800 ...")

Comment: I just press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`R` (goes to a console for `manage.py`) and I type `runserver`

Comment: @dirkgroten and nope I don't see it below the startup log.

Comment: don't runserver from the manage.py tab. Create a run configuration and then run it. (ctrl-R or ctrl-D to run it in debug mode) That way if you run in debug mode you can set breakpoints. You'll see all the output in the Run/Debug console.

Comment: @dirkgroten tried that too. Please correct me if I am wrong: Run > Run (i.e. `Alt`+`Shift`+`F10`) and selected my app. Nothing printed to console either.

Comment: @dirkgroten how do u do ctrl-R or ctrl-D. doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: shortcuts might be different i'm on macos. They are the top two options in the Run menu.

Comment: ran in debug mode too. nothing.

Comment: remove (comment them out) your LOGGING settings for now. Everything should show up below the startup log in your "Run" or "Debug" console tab.

Comment: @dirkgroten already removed LOGGING. nothing still.

Comment: you see the startup log? And when you make a request to one of your view you see the requests in red? e.g. `"GET /user/profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 50235`

Comment: and do you have DEBUG=True in your settings?

Comment: To your last two questions, yes. I tried adding LOGGING back into `settings.py`, refreshed it, and removed it. Now I see the logs. Strange!

Comment: Now you might want to ask a different question on SO showing your LOGGING settings if you can’t understand why they don’t work.

Comment: Tip: get familiar with the debug run mode, setting breakpoints, and inspecting variables. So much better than staring at code that doesn’t work trying to figure out why. :)

Comment: Sorry - the logs stopped showing again. Not sure why. I didn't change any settings. I stopped seeing `"GET /user/profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 50235` as well. But my page continues to load!

Comment: Do you have the app running multiple times on different ports? Maybe a terminal session still running?

Comment: Nope. I made sure I stopped all parallel apps that were running before running the app.

Comment: The address bar in your browser shows the correct port? I really can’t think of anything else. Except restarting your machine and pycharm.

Comment: Or do you have already multiple settings files (preparing for production) and is your run config using the correct one?

Comment: I changed some code in `views.py` and it started showing again. Seriously very weird. Both times when it logged and didn't log, my page loaded just fine.

Comment: Can’t think of anything than that either you have two processes running for some reason (restart your machine) or your LOGGING settings are messing things up.

Comment: You must be right. I stopped the server and page continued to load. Closed and reopened Pycharm and it worked everytime.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#views.py

import logging
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Customer

def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        groups = Customer.objections.select_related('group').values('name', 'address', 'group__name', 'group__limit')
        print(groups)
        for item in groups:
            logging.info('Your message')
            print(item)
        context = {'group_list': {'data': list(groups)}}
        logging.debug('Your message')
        return render(request, 'index.html', context, request.user)
    else:
        logging.info('Your message')
        return redirect('/accounts/login')
```

docs: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html

Comment: if you use logger, the Django logging in console deactivates and you must write your logger messages in each views (if need)

Comment: “Django logging in console deactivates” is not correct.

Comment: This didn't help. Having said, I did not setup the LOGGING parameters in `settings.py`.